# An Error Was Encountered : Non-existent class: Table

Tags: regular-expressions

Prior this was working. I transfer few files and later it stop working and after login to expression engine when I go to modify -> entry, it shows me an error was encountered.

Comment: For people to be able to help you, you will need to provide more information than this.  What version of EE are you using?  It would also help if you could give more details of the issue you are encountering - and maybe post the error message you see?  If you are not sure how to put a question in a form that others can answer, have a look at some questions here that have been answered, to see what kind of information is usually supplied.

Comment: Expression engine v2.7.2 i am using. Not sure what happening. When i login to cpanel then I do to Modify tab and click on entry I get the error showing "An Error Was Encountered : Non-existent class: Table"